# MySql query merging tables and populating dataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, forms, datagridview

I'm creating a small c# application linked to an online MySql database to further my knowledge on these 2 things.

In my database I have 2 tables "user" and "dvd" and they are build as this:

- user: ID, GEBRUIKERSNAAM, PASWOORD
- dvd: ID, TITLE,DUUR,USERID,...

What I'm trying to do now is take a colum from each table and display them in a dataGridView.
The colum's that I want are from table dvd: TITEL and from table user: GEBRUIKERSNAAM.

A dvd is linked to a user (One user many dvd's), using the ID from table user and the foreign key USERID from table dvd.

As a result I want to show 2 colums in my dataGridView one for the dvd's titel and the other kekst to the first for the owner of the dvd (witch is the GEBRUIKRSNAAM colum).

To do this I wrote the following code:

```
SELECT  'TITEL', dvd.TITEL
FROM xxx.dvd
UNION ALL 
SELECT  'GEBRUIKERSNAAM', user.GEBRUIKERSNAAM
FROM xxx.user
INNER JOIN xxx.dvd ON user.ID = dvd.USERID
WHERE user.ID = xxx.dvd.USERID;
```

This however gives me 2 problems:

- If I use it directly on my database (using the SQL tab from
  phpMyAdmin) it works, but merges the 2 colums into one what I don't want. I think the problem here is the "Union All" piece, but I don't know how else to do this.
- If I try to use this code using my c# application I get the following error: "Functionality SelectCommand.Connection is not initialized". I know the problem is somewere in this query because if I try it with a different query my code works like it is supposed to. (It fills the dataGridView).

  ```
       try
  {

      MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT TITEL FROM xxx.dvd UNION ALL SELECT  GEBRUIKERSNAAM FROM xxx.user INNER JOIN xxx.dvd ON user.ID = dvd.USERID WHERE user.ID = xxx.dvd.USERID;");
      myConn.Open();
      MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
      sda.SelectCommand = SelectCommand;
      DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
      sda.Fill(dbdataset);
      BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

      bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
      dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
      sda.Update(dbdataset);

  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
  myConn.Close();
  ```

Any help,tips or correct ways of doing something (best practice) on this problem are welcome
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally clear on what your goal is, but maybe some part of this will help you:

```
SELECT U.GEBRUIKERSNAAM, D.TITLE 
FROM dvd D JOIN user U ON D.USERID = U.ID 
WHERE D.ID = 1
```

This will take the dvd table, and for each entry look up the user whose ID matches D.USERID.  From that merged row, it will select the U.GEBRUIKERSNAAM and D.TITLE, but only results where the dvd ID is 1.

Please comment if there are further questions.  I hope I understood your goal correctly.  It may be easier if you gave me an example of what your desired output should look like & have me write the query.

Comment: Hi, thx for helping me. I tried the code you gave me but I got the same problem I came across before. GEBRUIKERSNAAM and TITLE are colums from differnet tables. When I ran the code you gave I got the error: " Unknown column 'dvd.TITLE' in 'field list'". I will edit my question to try and make it more clear what it is I'm trying to get.

Comment: I just noticed that in one place you spell it "TITEL" and in the other you spell it "TITLE".  Perhaps it should be D.TITEL?

Comment: Thanks alot, I can't belief I didn't see that... I indeed misspelled my columname.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly then you need to display 2 columns where you to show wht user has hired the DVD for that you should use the query:

select d.TITLE, u.GEBRUIKERSNAAM 
from dvd d 
Inner join user u 
ON u.ID = d.USERID